# Lease equipment to someone or sell it?

Tags: start-up, lease

I am currently designing a data logging system for an interested party. The cost of the items assembly and purchase is about $100 (board, power supply, 2 sensors). I want to get lets say 15$/month subscription out of this, to offer analytics, SMS, and whatever else comes to mind in the future.

Do I:

1. sell him the equipment and ask for a subscription? (without a subscription the data logger is useless)
2. lease him the equipment ($100 once) and ask for a subscription? (without a subscription the data logger is useless).
3. sell him the equipment with a minimum functionality and offer optional subscription? (what is the new price $100 + ? in case he does not want the subscription?)
4. do something completely different?

PS. I want a subscription...

Comment: Does the equipment have any value to you if the customer no longer wants it?

Comment: only if i apply the third bullet point @CharlesFox

Comment: What does your customer want? What's the expected timeframe they'd want to use this over (do you expect them to keep it for years, or do you expect people to move on after a few months)? Is this really just one customer?

Comment: its one customer now. but other locals will follow its cheap, easy and usefull. lets say they use it for 1 year if the subscription is at a proper price.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about small business that has no bearing on **personal** finance.  https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com @RonJohn, its in the name. It also says Personal Finance & **MONEY**. Do you propose another solution?

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis the emphasis is on **personal** finance and money, and I took a direct quote from the help page: "Please note that the following subjects are considered **off-topic here**: Questions about **small business** that have **no bearing** on **personal** finance".

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis and no, I have no suggestion for what other SE site to post this on.

Comment: I have no bussiness yet. So lets call it personal finance for now. When i get the deal ill erase the question.

Comment: @GeorgePamfilis, this issue is this question really doesn't have anything to do with personal finance or money.  Sale vs lease is a liability and accounting question and subscriptions are about contracting and again accounting.  What does the interested party want to do, does that person want to pay a subscription?  Why not just charge $1,000 and deliver some piece of hardware that works?  It feels like you need to talk to your interested party.

Comment: Bundle the subscription. so make it $20 a month and say it includes the hardware. and lock in a 2 year commitment. or say he can buy the equipment for $100 and just $15 with no lock if he objects.

Answer (score 0):

> PS. I want a subscription...

Then make it a subscription service and lease them the hardware.

Comment: And factor the cost of the hardware into the subscription fee.